# Ideal circuit for opto-isolated push button input

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, button, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm trying to design an isolated and robust push button circuit. I have to take precautions for glitching, debouncing etc.. I want to use an opto-isolator. I drew a simple schematic but I'm not sure if it is ideal. I have 10 push buttons and I will apply same circuit for all.

- Will it cause any problem while getting interrupt (I'm planning to use external interrupts on MCU firmware)
- Need I still use a capacitor to debounce ?
- Need I still use 74HC14? Is it useful ?

I need advice about this button issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you know why you chose a 74HC14 or was it just a guess?

Comment: Why do want to have an interrupt from a simple pushbutton? And interrupts from all 10 of them? Usually, that is a sign of asking trouble. Do you have any reason to trigger interrupts from a pushbutton?

Comment: @Andyaka I have never used it but  as i read  it provides schmit triggering and it helps debouncing.

Comment: @Justme Maybe I don't use interrput I'm not sure yet. But all push buttons have different missions(starting motors and etc.) Users can push 3 buttons continously but the other 7 for just one time per round.

Comment: Keep the transfer ratio of your opto in mind. The circuit you've made has no debouncing in it and you will want that (you can place the capacitor "behind" the 10k at the input). The use of a schmitt trigger is for sure a good idea. If you want to use interrupts you might want to consider binding together all the signals with an OR gate and have only one interrupt for all inputs (and than read the inputs).

Comment: Many MCUs have Schmitt trigger inputs either by default or as a configurable option. Is that not the case in yours?

Comment: There are opto-isolators with built-in Schmitt trigger outputs. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/voh1016ab-1767805.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to put the capacitor after the resistor, making a low pass filter with a 1msec time constant which should be enough for most all switches.

You may not need the inverter depending on your logic of the MCU input (depending on if reset is asserted high or if reset is asserted low).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fui6fJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Actually using inverter is not for invert function just for schmit triggering. In addition I don't want to take out VCC from PCB so  I have to design isolated circuit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need interrupts for very important stuff **IF** your MCU is slowed down by doing a lot of other stuff. That aside, Arduino for example only have two interrupt pins.
2. You don't need the capacitor, do the de-bouncing in software side.
3. No you don't need 74HC14, unless your application requires which in this case I don't see the need.

For driving the LEDs, I'd use a constant current source and then move the push button to the low side of circuit, that way you can eliminate 10 resistors and overall have a neat looking PCB.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the modern way is to handle the debouncing in firmware. That way, you can tweak debounce times in code instead of fixed hardware values. But this is the scheme I would useif I had to do an isolated hardware debouncer. Note: the values and components are arbitrary and were chosen purely for my convivence from the schematic tool. Adjust accordingly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIDvjF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Switch R1 and Q1 if you want inverted logic.